# Getting an empty AJAX response from wordpress function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm getting an empty AJAX response from my function in my `functions.php`. Here's my function that processes the AJAX request.

```
function dynamic_date() {
check_ajax_referer('dynamic_date_nonce');
$fdate = $_GET['my_date'];
$date[] = explode("-",$fdate);
$year = $date[0];
$month = $date[1];
$args = array('year' => $year,'monthnum' => $month);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if($loop->have_posts()) { 
while($loop->have_posts()) { 
the_post();
echo get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
} 
} wp_reset_query();
die('');
}
```

And this is the AJAX call:

```
function _do_ajax(obj) {
    var element = $(obj); //our link object
    var url = wpAjax.unserialize(element.attr('href'));
    var s = {};
    s.response = 'ajax-response';
    s.type = "GET";
    s.url = sortbydate.ajax_url;
    s.dataType = "HTML";
    s.data = $.extend(s.data, { action: url.action, _ajax_nonce: url._wpnonce, my_date: url.my_date });
    s.global = false;
    s.timeout = 30000;
    s.success = function(data) {
        $("body.blog #content").fadeIn(500).append(data);
        alert(data);            
    } //End success
    s.error = function(r) {
        alert("Epic Fail!");    
    }
    $.ajax(s);
} //end _do_ajax
$.get_my_comments.init();
});
```

Now if I remove the wordpress loop and just echo $year and $month it appends to the container and works fine. When I add the loop though I get an empty response and nothing is displayed.

Am I handling the response properly?

Comment: Do you have `post-format` wise template parts ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera I'm sorry, no, what is `post-format`? If it helps, I'm using the child theme for the twentyeleven theme. So everything is completely generic, I;m just using it for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

So, this will look for `content-format.php` file and in this case `formats` are

```
aside, chat, gallery, link, image, quote, status, video, audio
```

So, depending on the `format` of the post, `WordPress` will look for a file in template's root folder. So, make sure, you have corresponding files, such as, `content-aside.php`, `content-chat.php` and so on (if you have these types of posts). For, default/normal post, `get_post_format()` returns `false`, so try this instead

```
$format = get_post_format();
if ( false === $format ) {
    $format = 'standard';
}
get_template_part( 'content', $format );
```

Finally, make sure that, you have posts according to your query, just `var_dump($loop)` and see if you really get any result or is it empty at all.

If you don't have any `post-format` specific posts then, you may use,

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'loop' );
```

and change your file name to `content-loop.php`, so `WordPress` will look for/include `content-loop.php` or `content.php` file when you call `get_template_part( 'content', 'loop' );`.

Comment: Thanks man, really appreciate it, this sounds like the right direction. I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: Sigh... yup, I just did a var_dump($loop) didn't return any posts haha so I fixed it, kind of. For some reason it's only working with query_posts at the moment and not wp_query, can you think of a reason why?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts